# flutter application/vnd.android.package-archive parse error

Tags: flutter

In Flutter after building appliciation in release mode, we get this error on some device such as `g4+` when we want to install,

i don't know why we get this error and how we can resolve that

Answer (score 0):

Installation can give the specified error at least in following cases:

- **Name of the package is changed after signing**: Use the exact name as
  the signed package is (instead, adjust the name in Manifest)
- **Package is compiled against on higher API level**: Correct the API
  level in Manifest file
- **Package is executed from SD-card**: Run (install) the apk file from
  phones memory OR use adb command to install it